# add new input field on input

Tags: html, dynamic, input, field

Good day users,

I want to make an form with an input field, and when an users starts to type in that input field another input field appears below it. This so the user can add multiple products without seeing an list of 20 input fields but just see an new input field when they type in the first one.

I hope some1 here knows where i can look for this.

Kind regards,

Augus

Comment: you can do it dynamically, for example when the user filled or type minimum number of characters you can display the next input field using script. Please check this & google it.http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @karthikrangaraj pointed out in his comment, you can do it attaching an `onkeyup` event handler to those inputs, and calling there a function that will dinamically add the elements to the container.

You'll have to keep track of which input fields have already created a child input in order to avoid creating new fields at every key press, and you'll also have to keep track of the number of elements added in order to assign coherent `name`/`id` attributes to the newly created elements.

See a basic working example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/By5Q2/).

Comment: Nice example, this is getting me alot further. But with my experience with javascript i would have another question for you is it possible to make an new div with text and the input beneath it?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can create a new `<div>` element and add the `<input>` to it. Then add the `<div>` to the container element. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/By5Q2/12/).

Comment: Wow thanks! Now i only need to figure out how i can put some text and another input in that div :p. But ur help is great!

Comment: You can append text to an element with, for instance `myDivElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Some random text."));`. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/By5Q2/29/) for reference. As for adding another `<input>`, just follow the pattern in the example :-)

Comment: Ur great! this will let me add all the things i need.

Comment: I've cleaned up a little the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/By5Q2/41/) for you. You can add the first element with a call to the add function in an `onload` event handler